# Geometrically proving that upper matrices determinant is the product of its diagonal.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, measure-theory

I'm trying to prove that the determinant of an upper or lower matrix is the product of its diagonals. Other proofs I've seen lean on the Laplace formula. I want to use the geometric interpretation of the determinant instead (the measure of the parallelopipid contained between the column vectors). For a $2 \times 2$ matrix, this is easy to see geometrically. Consider $$M = \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   a & b \\
   0 & c \\
  \end{array} } \right]$$

Considering the second column as the x-axis, we get the diagram below formed by the row vectors:

[image]

Here, it is easy to see that the additional areas cancel out and the new shape should have the same area as the square, making $b$ irrelevant to the determinant (OABC has the same area as OAXY).

But I'm having a hard time generalizing this to $n$ or even $3$ dimensions.

I'm also interested in visualizing what that grey shape will look like for the three dimensional case.

Comment: This might be circular but what if you start with the identity matrix and that the parallelopiped (or really cube) has volume 1. Now basic operations such as scaling a row scales the entire volume by that. The geometric intuition is hopefully clear. We can build any upper triangular matrix now by scaling rows and adding a multiple of one row to another. Adding this multiple doesn't change volume (why?). This is the fact you've noted above. $b$ "shears" and pushes hyperplanes parallel to its axis, and so doesn't affect volume. Same idea there!